# Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource. Need Solution

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, maven, model-view-controller

**Here is the error**

> 23-Feb-2018 17:14:17.569 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring
>   WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 23-Feb-2018
>   17:14:17.783 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring
>   root WebApplicationContext 23-Feb-2018 17:14:19.361 SEVERE [RMI TCP
>   Connection(4)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception
>   sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
>   [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener] 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

applicationContext.xml

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lpg</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">root</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password"></prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <!--prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop-->
        </props>
    </property>
    <!--property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.all.packages.model.City</value>
            <value>com.all.packages.model.Country</value>
            <value>com.all.packages.model.District</value>
            <value>com.all.packages.model.State</value>
        </list>
    </property-->
    <!--property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crm</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
        </props>
    </property-->
</bean>

<!-- Spring Email Sender Bean Configuration -->

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">

    <!--property name="host" value="smtp.mail.yahoo.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="" />
    <property name="password" value="" /-->
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="25"/>
    <property name="username" value="jyotirmoy.saha@gmail.com"/>
    <property name="password" value="prodsoftpakak2007"/>

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">465</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>

<!-- Spring Email Attachment Configuration -->

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- Maximum Upload Size In Bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" />
    <!-- Maximum Size Of File In Memory (In Bytes) -->
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" />

</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
      class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

Where is the error please do help.I am using Intellij Idea

Comment: Why have you commented all sections relatives to annotated classes and db info? Can your show also your Dao and services(if possible)?

Comment: From your error output you are getting a NoClassDefFoundError indicating that a class you depend on is not present in your runtime. The class is located in i.e. jaxb-api. Take a look here; http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api, it includes details on how to add dependencies to your build system definition files.